# Javascript event not working on load

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript event which calculates a price of something according to 2 variables (price and days that the product is used). The function is called on the 2 input elements like this: `onkeyup=calc(this.form)`, this works like a charm.

I've connected a DB with these 2 values and echo-ed them as values of the two input elements (which is successful) and added this to make the function happen when the page is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
         {
             calc(form);
         }; 
</script>
```

The problem is that the result of the calculation doesn't show up until I do something with one of the input elements.

The live version can be seen over here: http://www.websane.nl/macbook/opgeslagen.php?id=1

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Try this: `window.onload = function() { calc(document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]); };`

Comment: Or `window.onload = function() { calc(document.forms[0]); };`

Comment: Both work great! Thanks a lot, I've learned something again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `form` in the statement `calc(form);` isn't anything--it's undefined. Which makes sense--not only can there be many forms in an HTML document (so it could never automatically work), you never bound the `form` variable to any one of them. To get a reference to a *particular* form, you can use several techniques:

- `document.getElementsbyTagName('form')[0]`
- `document.forms[0]`
- `document.forms.formname`
- `document.getElementById('theFormId')`

Replace `form` in your `onload` event with one of the above and things should work. There could be many other ways to get a reference to a form.